# mailjet rest api /send doesn't work

Tags: api, send, mailjet

I tried this example in the console from the https://dev.mailjet.com/ :

```
curl -s  -X POST --user "user:pass"  https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/send  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**and the result is always**

> { "ErrorInfo" : "", "ErrorMessage" : "Unknown resource: \"send\"",
>   "StatusCode" : 400 }

If I try other get requests, like /contact the result is with success.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're using is not the right one. Please change it to `https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send`.

Please visit the dedicated API guide for our transactional API here https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#send-transactional-email

Hope it helps.

hAPI coding with Mailjet API!